# Как вывести тег через условие if hugo?

Tags: golang, шаблонизаторы

У меня есть код в шаблонизаторе hugo, который должен добавить скрипт, если в статье параметр равен нужному значению.

Front Matter статьи. Тут мне нужен параметр header_class

```
---
title: "Replaced header"
header_class: "replaced-header"
---
```

Если header_class = "replaces-header", вывести код. Попробовал реализовать так:

```
{{ if isset .Params.header_class "replaced-header" }}
<script>
    let replacedHeader = document.querySelector('.replaced-header');
    window.onscroll = function() {
        let breakPoint = 100;
        let scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if(scroll > breakPoint) {
            replacedHeader.classList.add('replaced-header--scrolled');
        }
    };
</script>
{{ end }}
```

Код не работает. Как нужно задать условие в этом случае?

Answer (score 0):

Получил ответ на другом форуме, публикую его здесь.
Любой из этих трёх методов будет рабочим:

```
  {{ if isset .Params "header_class" }}
    {{ .Params.header_class }}
  {{ end }}

  {{ with .Params.header_class }}
    {{ . }}
  {{ end }}

  {{ with .Param "header_class" }}
    {{ . }}
  {{ end }}
```

Или так:

```
{{ with $.Param "header_class" }}
{{ if ( eq . "replaced-header") }}
My script
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```